# Cannot animate view assigned from IBOutlet

Tags: animation, uiview, uistoryboard, iboutlet

Recently I came across a problem with animating `UIViews` which are assigned through an `IBOutlet`. Everything works fine when instantiating the view in code and then animating it. But if it is created in the storyboard and assigned through an `IBOutlet` no animations are working. Is there something I am missing?

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *foreground;
```

I am using animation blocks

```
      [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{

        NSLog(@"oldForegroundFrame %@, newForeGroundFrame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.foreground.frame), NSStringFromCGRect(foregroundFrame));

         self.foreground.frame = foregroundFrame;

        NSLog(@"oldForegroundFrame %@, newForeGroundFrame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.foreground.frame), NSStringFromCGRect(foregroundFrame));            

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"oldForegroundFrame %@, newForeGroundFrame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.foreground.frame), NSStringFromCGRect(foregroundFrame));  

    }];
```

The print out from NSLog shows that the frame is being set correct after the assignment, but on completion it is being reset to the original position.

oldForegroundFrame {{0, 0}, {320, 133}}, newForeGroundFrame: {{0, -45}, {320, 45}}
oldForegroundFrame {{0, -45}, {320, 45}}, newForeGroundFrame: {{0, -45}, {320, 45}}
oldForegroundFrame {{0, 0}, {320, 133}}, newForeGroundFrame: {{0, -45}, {320, 45}}

Comment: Can you post the declaration of the `IBOutlet`? Also try to `NSLog` both `foreground` and `foregroundFrame` before the assignment in order to verify that your object is not `nil` and the target frame is different from the source frame.

Comment: I updated my question and included NSLog print outs

Comment: Answered this problem in my other post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881513/uiimageview-animation-not-working-correctly